# Is Adobe Acrobat's icon a special function?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, polar-coordinates

[image]

It looks like a function in polar coordinates.

Is it a special function ?

Comment: This a very good point ! I never thought about it and you are pobably right ! Thanks for the question. Cheers :-)

Comment: I'd wager that the person who designed the logo had never even heard of "polar coordinates". The logo has a stylish assymetry. The typical designer would say that the functions graphs shown below are "mechanical" or "lifeless" or just plain boring. Mathematicians and graphical designers have very different tastes (thankfully).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The logo dates back to Adobe Reader v1.0. ([link](https://www.google.com/search?q=adobe+acrobat+1.0&tbm=isch)) I always thought it was chosen simply because it looks like the letter A for Acrobat.

A parametric function that approximates the logo is:
$$x(t)=5\cos(t)\times \left(\sin(t+.5)+\cos(3t+.5) \right) \\
y(t)=5\sin(t)\times \left(\sin(t+.5)-\cos(3t+.5) \right) $$
[image: Function graph]

Comment: The graph can be seen here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5Bx%28t%29%3D5cos%28t%29%C3%97%28sin%28t%2B.5%29%2Bcos%283t%2B.5%29%29%2Cy%28t%29%3D5sin%28t%29%C3%97%28sin%28t%2B.5%29%E2%88%92cos%283t%2B.5%29%29%5D

Comment: How did you find this equation ?

Comment: I just worked it out actually... Trial and error. It took a little playing around with, but I eventually got it.
I started with a 3-leaf clover 
$x = \cos(3t) \cos t$, $y = \cos(3t) \sin t $. The key was getting it to avoid the origin. I knew I needed to add something to interact with the cos(3t), so I added a sin(t) and eureka! The final step was to rotate by 0.5, and scale by 5.

Answer (score 11):

It bears a strong resemblance to (in cartesian coordinates)
$ x = \cos(t) + 3 \cos(2 t)/4, y = \sin(t) - 3 \sin(2 t)/4$ 
but not quite as symmetric.

[image]

Comment: Meta-question: How did you approach this, i.e. finding an equation to match a given visual description?

Comment: I tried for $x+iy = \exp(it) + c \exp(ikt)$.  I wanted the two terms to have the same phase for $t = 0, 2\pi/3, -2\pi/3$, which led to $k=-2$.  Then just some fiddling with $c$ to get it to look right.

Answer (score 2):

[image: acrobat C4D formula spline]

Thanks you guys! Very grateful for this discussion. This is just what I was looking for. It's a Cinema4D Formula Object. Did a little Z tweaking to make it loop like Acrobat Logo. Apologies for my home made Z formula, kinda hacked at it. Sure there is a better solution.

- $X= 300 \cdot \cos(t) \cdot (\sin(t+.5) +\cos(3t+.5))$
- $Y= 300 \cdot \sin(t) \cdot (\sin(t+.5)  -\cos(3t+.5))$
- $Z= 10 \cdot \cos(t) \cdot 10 \cdot \sin(t)$
- TMin $=-1.571$
- TMin $=1.571$

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit like a deltoid, which belongs to the family of [Kakeya sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakeya_set). It was thought to be the solution to the problem of finding the minimal area you need to rotate a needle in the plane.